# jQuery corresponding radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html

I have some divs, each with a radio button and a drop-down box.  What is some simple jQuery to, on selection of the drop-down box, check the radio button within the same div?

```
<div id="x">
  <%= radio_button_tag "opt", "gene", false %>
  <%= select_tag "opt", options_for_select(@genes), { :multiple => false, :class => 'selectors'} %>
</div><br/>
```

Comment: Could you show us the actual HTML generated?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a `div` that contains one or more radio buttons and a drop-down menu with one or more options.  When the user selects an option from the drop-down menu, then some corresponding radio button is checked (enabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <input id="r1" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label for="r1">Radio me</label>
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="some-class">
    <input id="r2" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label for="r2">Radio me</label>
    <select>
        <option>four</option>
        <option>five</option>
        <option>six</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="some-class">
    <input id="r3" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label for="r3">Radio me</label>
    <select>
        <option>seven</option>
        <option>eight</option>
        <option>nine</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

then your JavaScript could look something like this:

```
$('div.some-class > select').live('change', function ()
{
    $(this).prevAll('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/CBGMD/

Comment: I was going to guarantee that the div only has the two elements, but I like the use of `.prev`. Nicely done, though why the use of live?

Comment: I generally try to minimize the number of event listeners in my DOM, and (as I'm sure you know) `.live()` will create only one listener, regardless of the number of `div.some-class > select` elements.

Comment: About using `.live` vs. `.bind`, does jQuery create one listener on the `select` element or one for each `option` within the select?

Comment: @Marc: in the `.bind('change', callback)` case, which is equivalent to `.change(callback)`, one listener is created for each element in the jQuery object which `.bind()` is called on. In this case, that would be one listener per `select`.

Comment: @MattBall: Indeed true, though I'm always skeptical with how it needs to monitor the DOM for changes and the overhead incurred. Trivial, but always keep it in the back of my mind. ;-)

Comment: @Matt Ball: So in your example, by using `.live` there is one listener created even though the DOM has three `div`'s picked out by your selector `$(div.some-class > select)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').children('input[type=radio]').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Comment: FYI, `.parent().children()` = [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). You can also use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) & [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) (among  [several others](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/))

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectors').change(function() {
    $(this).prev().attr('checked', true);
});
```